# Como usar um array dentro getView em um adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Eis o meu problema, eu estou passando uma sequência de arrays para um adapter que deve ser colocado dentro de uma listview, dentre estes tenho um array bidimensional chamado materiais :

```
public View onCreateView(...){
...
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Meus arrays que vão dentro do array bidimensional
    int[] mat1 = new int[]{R.drawable.bronze};
    int[] mat2 = new int[]{R.drawable.prata};
    int[] mat3 = new int[]{R.drawable.ouro};

    int[] imagens = new int[]{R.drawable.adaga, R.drawable.espada, R.drawable.machado};
    String[] nomes = new String[]{"Adaga", "Espada", "Machado"};
    int[][] materiais = new int[][]{mat1, mat2, mat3}; // Meu array bidimensional.
    String[] desc = new String[]{"Uma adaga", "Uma espada", "Um machado"};
    int[] cores = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.cores);

    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menuFerreiroMateriaisListView);
    listView.setAdapter(new FragFerreiroArrayAdapter(getActivity(), imagens, nomes, materiais, desc, cores));

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

O custom adapter que recebe os arrays é este, a ideia é criar uma lista de itens (no meu caso, uma adaga, uma espada e um machado), aonde cada um tem um nome, uma imagem, uma descrição e uma lista de ícones que seriam os materiais usados para criar aquele item:

```
public class FragFerreiroArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final String TAG = "FragFerreiro";

private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final Context context;

// Este é o construtor chamado que recebe o array bidimensional da class anterior
public FragFerreiroArrayAdapter(Context context, int[] imagens, String[] nomes, int[][] materiais, String[] desc, int[] cores) {
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

    //int[] teste = new int[] {R.drawable.bronze};

    // Aqui eu crio um novo objeto item que vai ser
    // referente a uma linha dentro do meu layout,
    // repare que ele recebe o valor de array materiais[]
    // que é na verdade um array de int definido na classe
    // anterior.
    for (int i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
        mItems.add(new Item(imagens[i], nomes[i], materiais[i], desc[i], cores[i]));
        //mItems.add(new Item(imagens[i], nomes[i], teste, desc[i], cores[i]));
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    // TODO verificar esse mêtodo
    return mItems.get(i).imagem;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ImageView imagemItem;
    TextView nomeItem;
    LinearLayout materiaisItem;
    TextView descricaoItem;

    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem, v.findViewById(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem));
        v.setTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_nome, v.findViewById(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_nome));
        v.setTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_materiais_necessarios, v.findViewById(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_materiais_necessarios));
        v.setTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_descricao, v.findViewById(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_descricao));
    }

    Item itemAtual = getItem(i);

    imagemItem = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem);
    imagemItem.setImageResource(itemAtual.imagem);

    nomeItem = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_nome);
    nomeItem.setText(itemAtual.nome);

    // Este é um linear layout envolvido em um horizontal scroll view que deve receber uma lista de ícones.
    materiaisItem = (LinearLayout) v.getTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_materiais_necessarios);

    // Esta parte do código está dando MUITA dor de cabeça.
    for(int e=0;e<itemAtual.materiais.length;e++)
    {
        ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
        imagem.setImageResource(itemAtual.materiais[e]);
        materiaisItem.addView(imagem);
    }

    descricaoItem = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_descricao);
    descricaoItem.setText(itemAtual.descricao);

    // TODO adicionar cor de fundo

    return v;
}

private static class Item {
    public final int imagem;
    public final String nome;
    int[] materiais;
    public final String descricao;
    public final int cor;
    private final String TAG = "Item";

    Item(int imagem, String nome, int[] materiais, String descricao, int cor) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.materiais = materiais;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.cor = cor;
    }
}
}
```

A lista é criada corretamente como esperado e as linhas são adicionadas corretamente:

[image: linhas criadas]

Entretanto, nesta parte do código, por algum motivo ele define a primeira linha com todos os ícones passados pelo array materiais como pode ser visto acima, aonde deveria haver apenas uma imagem de um "cobre", há 2 imagens de cobre e mais 1 de prata e outra de ouro:

```
    for(int e=0;e<itemAtual.materiais.length;e++)
    {
        ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
        imagem.setImageResource(itemAtual.materiais[e]);
        materiaisItem.addView(imagem);
    }
```

Eu já tentei verificar a origem do problema colocando saídas de texto para o log em cada passo contando os valores do array e printando os mesmos. Eu estou realmente sem ideias, fiz esse pequeno projeto exatamente pra aprender a usar custom adapters mas pelo que me parece, parei em um erro muito bobo e não consigo resolver.

Este é o XML do item criado no custom adapter:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:clickable="false" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_conteudo_interno"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_imagem"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_nome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_descricao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_nome"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_descricao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_materiais_necessarios"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_botao_criar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_conteudo_interno"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/menu_ferreiro_frag_materiais_item_conteudo_interno"
    android:text="Criar" />
```

Comment: acho que seria mais interessante utilizar expandable list view se encaixa perfeitamente na sua abordagem

Comment: Caíque, a ideia é um item por lista sem alterar o tamanho, mas eu vou dar uma olhada pra ver se consigo usar expandable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

descobri o problema, como é possível perceber pelos mêtodos usados essa classe é um Fragmento que é inflada em uma Atividade:

```
public View onCreateView(...){
...
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(...) {
...
}
```

Esta é a atividade que recebe a classe acima, repare que ela tem como o view o menu_ferreiro_atividade:

```
public class MenuFerreiro extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_ferreiro_atividade);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Este é o XML em questão, ele tem um framelayout usado apenas para ser substituido pelo Fragmento selecionado pelo usuário:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>

    <Button
        ... />

    <Button
        ... />

    <Button
       ... />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuFerreiroFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Me parece que por eu estar usando "wrap_content" o Fragmento estava sendo renderizado 2 vezes pois a aplicação não tinha o tamanho exato da tela, o que fazia com que todas as imagens fossem colocadas na primeira linha na primeira renderização e só depois tivessem a execução feita como esperado. Troquei de "wrap_content" para "fill_parent" e a tela começou a ser renderizada apenas uma vez, resultando na tela:

[image: Imagem correta]

**Resumo**:
Ao usar getView em um adaptador, lembre-se de que ele vai ser chamado mais de uma vez caso a view pai da view que você está mexendo tenha o **layout_height** e **layout_width** como **wrap_content**, o que vale de fato é a **view principal** e não necessariamente a view que recebe o que você está querendo inflar.